# Insert Reusable Content Button 

Tags: 2010

I have just created a new root site on SharePoint 2010.  I enabled the SharePoint Server Publishing Features at the Site Collection level, and then also at the Site level.  I then added some new reusable content items (one txt, one HTML)

When I edit a page, I can see the "Reusable Content" icon in the ribbon, but it is greyed out and says "This control is currently disabled".

Could this be because I am trying to edit the wrong kind of page? (I tried editing the site home page, and then tried creating a new page from scratch) or do I need to enable something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wiki Pages don't support Reusable Content by default. You would have to use Publishing Pages instead.